# In what Native American myth does the Sun stand still?

Tags: native-american, myth-identification

In [this answer](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/a/356/18), I saw this in a quote-in-a-quote:

> during the Third Age [equivalent to the Age in which the Popol Vuh places the invention of shooting out such magical darts], the sun stood still for one full day without moving from its place; - [*Esotericism of the Popol Vuh*: Chapter 10](http://www.theosociety.org/pasadena/popolvuh/pv-10.htm)

This caught my eye because the sun stands still in [Joshua 10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Joshua+10&version=NIV) in the Bible as well, so I went looking for this event in the Popol Vuh itself. However, I had difficulty finding it and was recently enlightened to the fact that, according to Hamlet's comment below, this does not appear in the Popol Vuh.

Where then does it appear? What Native American myth has the sun stand still for a full day?

Comment: It's not in the Popol Vuh, the source was talking about a different myth and comparing it to the popol vuh.

Comment: @Christofian: Which myth then?

Comment: I know this post was from a long time ago, but I've been looking for similar stories. Since the sun stood still a whole day, there must be some stories from elsewhere in the world of the same event. I was thinking, though, that since the sun stood still in the middle-east, that other parts of the world would experience darkness for an entire day, with the sun never rising that day.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This tale appears to come from [Toltec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toltec) mythology, related to us by the [Aztec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec) and preserved in later Mexican source. The Ixtlilxochitl your source cites is almost certainly [Fernando de Alva Cortés Ixtlilxochitl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_de_Alva_Cort%C3%A9s_Ixtlilxochitl), an early modern native historian from [New Spain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Spain). He wrote that:

> In the year 8 Tochtli, which was 1,347 years after the second calamity and 4,779 years since the creation of the world, it is recorded in their history that **the sun stood still one natural day without moving**, and a myth evolved wherein a mosquito saw the sun suspended in the air in a pensive mood and said, "Lord of the world, why are you standing still and why are you in such deep thought? Why are you not doing the work you are supposed to do? Do you want to destroy the world as before?" And the mosquito said many other things to the sun, but the sun still did not move. The mosquito then stung the sun on the leg, and seeing that his leg had been stung, the sun began again to move along its course as before.

This is clearly the same story described in your link. The preceding paragraphs make it clear that Ixtlilxochitl was, or at least thought he was, writing about the beliefs of the Toltecs.

> The Tultecas, consisting of seven men and their wives ...  they wandered for 104 years in different parts of the land until they settled in Huehue Tlapallan, their homeland.
>
> <sub>-  [*The Historical Works of Fernando de Alva Ixtlilxochitl.* Edited and annotated by Alfredo Chavero, 1892.](http://www.ancientamerica.org/library/media/382chapter11.htm)</sub>

Since pretty much all we know about Toltec mythology are second hand from the Aztecs, who viewed themselves as the Toltecs' successors, you could also consider this myth to be Aztec.